# Replacing CSS3 hover transition with jquery click event

Tags: jquery, css, click, hover

I have a series of images that use css3 to achieve a hover effect. When the use hovers over an image, a caption slides over. It is a very nice effect. On mobile, the user cannot see this hover effect because there is no hovering on mobile. Ideally, I want mobile users to see the caption when they "tap" (same as click) on the image. What is the best approach to convert a css hover selector into a click event? I would assume the best approach is to use jquery. But if I did soemthing like the following, I'm not sure how this would work with CSS3:

```
$("img").click(function(){
     perform css3 hover transitions now
});
```

I would place this in a conditional so it only applies to screens below 480px (mobile). My question is, how would I trigger these CSS3 hover transitions as a jquery click event on mobile screens? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sincerely i haven't tried jQuery Mobile yet, but this library provides pseudo-events for mouse events like [`vmouseover`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html), you can use this event, put the CSS `:hover` properties in another class and by firing the event add the class to the element:

```
$('img').live('vmouseover', function() {
      $(this).addClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me figure out a great solution...which is to simply use a click event with the normal jquery library. Because there is no anchor around the image, it works on both mobile and desktop (as a hover or click)

Answer (score 0):

According to this what you want is impossible.  The suggested fix is to duplicate the css in another, non-pseudo css class.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-triggering-css-pseudo-selectors-like-hover